# Smoothly changing background while hovering on an element

Tags: jquery, css

While searching the solution to my problem I've found an answer of the user Arun P Johny about how to make an effect of changing background

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $('.menu-item-1').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url("yadayadayada.jpg")')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

But how to make a smooth change?

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth change"? Like a fade-in?

Comment: yes, exactly, when one background image smoothly turns into another

Comment: css transitions are ok but what about modifying the code?

Comment: add an image with position absolute and zindex -1 and do a fadeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware this can't be done on a single element without extensive (and slow) javascripting where you animate the image sources per pixel. Seems bad to me.

Instead, add another element to your DOM and animate that one,and you can do it with CSS transitions. Easy, and fast.

Here's the important css parts:

```
body {
    background: url(image1.jpg);
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(image2.jpg);
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vza1oynq/) for you.

EDIT AFTER OP COMMENT:

Remove the `:hover` selector from the CSS, and modify your JS like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $div = $('div');
    $('.menu-item-1').hover(function(){
        $div.css({opactiy: 0})
    }, function() {
        $div.css({opacity: 1})
    })
})
```

Comment: the main idea is that background of a div should be changed while hover another element

Comment: Ok. No problem. Use the same basic aproach, but use your own jQuery event handler to trigger the CSS transition. I edited my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: this div contains another div, which contains a hover element. So, if the main div has opacity: 0, then all child elements are invisible, too

Comment: Well yeah, opacity is inherited. That's why I made the element absolute positioned. You need to put all your other content beside it, not in it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have it set up you could do something like

```
$('.myimage').on('mouseover', function(){
$('.backgroundimage').fadeOut("slow",     function(){ 
complete : function () {
$('.otherimage').fadeIn();
}
});
});
```

I am on my phone and haven't tried this code, it's just to give you an idea off the top of my head.